# Insert multiple items into a list at once in python

Tags: python, list

What is a pythonic way for inserting multiple items into a list?
Suppose I have :

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and I want b to be inserted into a, that is for example:

```
a = [1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c', 3]
```

What I have done is:

```
a.insert(2,None)
a[2:3] = b
```

or also:

```
a = a[0:2] + b + a[2:]
```

The last approach seems nicer because it is just one line, but the problem is that I think a new list is created, and if the list is very large could be a performance issue.

On the other hand, the first approach doesn't seem very pythonic.

Comment: You can use the extend()-method that is provided by the list-type. b.extend(a) for example would add the items of a to b.

Comment: @Supahupe but the OP wants the elements to be inserted in the middle of the list

Comment: @Supahupe I think the question is to insert the items in a specific place

Comment: No need to insert a value first, just use an empty slice: `a[2:2] = b`.

Comment: @Aswing Murugesh you are right that was not clear for me at first, thx

Comment: Martijn, I like your comment better than the linked answer.  It addresses this issue directly.